# Mozilla Firefox Add-On will not start

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I currently have created an extension on google chrome, and it works perfectly fine. I copied the exact folder for the extension and used Node's

```
jpm init

jpm xpi
```

commands for the folder containing the extension's files. The extension folder contains a manifest.json and a javascript file pointed to by the manifest's content scripts. After doing jpm init and jpm xpi, the folder now contains an index.js, package.json, and a few other files. I have sent the extension for signing, and while I wait, I wanted to give add-on a run. For some reason, with the add-on installed, nothing happens. Even though the extension works fine on google chrome, am I missing something that I need to add to the firefox extension? Perhaps, do I need to change something about the index.js or package.json? Unfortunately, I will not be able to post any of the code, but I can assure that it works fine on google chrome, so it should not be the javascript file that is the issue. I imagine I missed a step in the packaging/installation stage.

Comment: Firefox's and Chrome's extension development methodologies are not 100% compatible (yet). Try pressing CTRL + SHIFT + J and see what comes up in the console, in terms of errors, when you drag the .xpi into Firefox.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any significant errors. The only error I see is "ReferenceError: ga is not defined" in "main.js:77:13". Does this mean anything? I've never seen this error before.

Comment: Unless the main.js is a file from your extension, no. It's probably an error which is thrown due to your AdBlock blocking google analytics on a site. Unfortunately without code it's unlikely anyone could help, because your packaging steps look fine.

Answer (score 0):

jpm creates what's called an [sdk extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), the (new, still under development) chrome-compatible extension API is called [webextensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) in firefox.

So if you're trying to just drop code you've written for chrome into firefox then `jpm` is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: So sdk extensions is the way to go?